# How to fill picture box with lines C#

Tags: c#, image, lines

So I have to fill my picture box with lines, though I can't understand what I've done wrong.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        }
        public void Zimet()
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

            Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics();
            Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
            for (int i = 0; i < pb.Height; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen1, pb.Width, 0, 0, pb.Height);
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zimet();
        }
```

Comment: We don't understand what you did wrong either! Please add details about what went wrong. Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected output? You need to clarify what the issue is.

Comment: tnw, absolutely nothing happened. I presssed that button that i've created thou nothing happens when it should fill my picture box with red lines. :/

Answer (score 2):

There are actually three reasons why this code won't work, two of which have been mentioned in other answers:

1. your PictureBox isn't a control on the form (see answer by patchandchat)
2. wrong coordinates used in draw-line (see answer by Nicola Davidovic)

The third issue is that you can't draw onto a PictureBox like that, since when the paint event fires, anything you drew is lost. Create an Image, draw onto that, and then set the image of your PictureBox to that image:

```
public void Zimet()
{
    var image = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
    for (int i = 0; i < pb.Height; i++)
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, i, pb.Width, i);
    }
    pb.Image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First your `PictureBox` should be field of your `Form` and you should not create it every time you click a button. Second, your `DrawLine` call is bad, for instance if you want horizontal lines you would need to do something like this:

```
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
        for (int i = 0; i < pb.Height; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, i, pb.Width, i);
        }
```

But this would be the same as filling the pictureBox with Red color. Instead I suggest you skipping every other line by updating i+=2.

```
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
        for (int i = 0; i < pb.Height; i+=2)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen1, 0, i, pb.Width, i);
        }
```

Nevertheless, I would suggest you not using CreateGraphic() method but do all drawing in the Paint event handler. The reason for this is whenever your form is invalidated, your drawing will be erased. Use for instance some bool value that will be set when you click a button and then, if it is true do the drawing. Something like this:

```
public class Form1:Form
{
    PictureBox pb;
    bool drawLines = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Size = new Size(100,100);
        pb.Location = new Point(0,0);
        pb.Paint+=new PaintEventHandler(pb_Paint);
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
    private void pb_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(drawLines)
        {
            Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
            for (int i = 0; i < pb.Height; i+=2)
            {
               e.Graphic.DrawLine(pen1, pb.Width, 0, 0, pb.Height);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Zimet()
    {
        drawLines = true; //however this may look redundant, it is still OP's code
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Zimet();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Zimet()` function creates a `Picturebox` and draws to it, and then throws it away at the end of the function.

You need to call `SomeUiObject.Controls.Add(pb);` to actually put it on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `PictureBox pb` in the form constructor, and then another one in your `Zimet()` method. The one in the `Zimet()` method is local in scope to that method, so goes out of scope when the method returns.

Are you trying to draw lines in the `PictureBox` created in your constructor? Because that goes out of scope once your constructor has completed. Maybe create a field in your class to hold the `PictureBox` and then draw in that in your `Zimet()` method.